# Logon terminal server over RDP per powershell/cmd and execute commands

Tags: powershell, terminal, rdp

I have problems with the powershell and some ideas.

I would boot a computer in a company network each day on 9 o'clock.
For thats i must connect to the company terminal server.
After the wakeonlan i must connect on the terminal server per rdp to the client.

How I could do this?

I think I connect to the terminal server over RDP and execute the WOL command.
Then i execute the RDP connect command and connect to the client.
After five minutes i close the both RDP sessions.

I tried PsExec but thats only allowed in a local server directory.

Comment: Just what exactly is your problem? As long as there are open ports that would allow RDP and WOL, there should be no problem in connection "Your PC" -> "TS" -> "Client". Please try to restate or post some details.

Answer (score 0):

RDP is a graphical/interactive protocol/system. Although it can be done, GUI automation isn't PowerShell's speciality. Try looking into something like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

For RDP automation you could try something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET) (keep the form hidden), but it's a bad solution and I'm not sure it even works anymore on newer versions of Windows.

Comment: I remembered that you could use the rdp "mstsc.exe" with server parameters. For example I could send the command, remember the process and kill the process. Then I would need an bat script which executed on terminalserver on autostart which wakes the client. Something like this... It must work ...!

Comment: Not to be rude, but this is automation gone wrong. If you really need to automate WOL + rdp session(don't understand why) to a computer, then you should just run that as a scheduled task on the terminal server. RDP -> TS with script to WOL and RDP to another client.. That's a disaster waiting to happend.

Comment: Where I'm rude? :( -> I cant create WOL Task because i have no permissions in the company network for unattended tasks...  But thats a great idea.. CMD which would be executed from remote computer. Then i must only know how to execute commands remotely :S

Comment: You weren't rude, I was just starting my comment with something similar to "no offence, but... ". :)